# How to format output with write.table

Tags: r, write.table

I apologize if this is an easy question. I am trying to use the points from the MixSim package in R to act as the sampling points in an old Fortran program because I like the way that MixSim creates sampling points better, but am using the Fortran program to simulate vegetation data across many levels of beta diversity, alpha diversity, etc.

I generate my data in MixSim by:

```
d=MixSim(BarOmega=0.000,MaxOmega=0.000,K=4,p=3,ecc=0.99,int=c(10,90),PiLow=0.1)
m=simdataset(n=10,Pi=d$Pi,Mu=d$Mu,S=d$S)
```

And if I do use write.table, this is what I get

```
write.table(m$X,file="example.txt",quote=F,row.names=F)
V1 V2 V3
87.540626647788 62.8444539443256 17.0026406651813
83.9939847940881 65.0069747775257 18.8676229149976
84.4477456535804 63.6892673685408 18.6384437248469
84.7684968694547 65.4610993744652 17.6252989584773
13.4600970937604 16.9988156469822 49.6810813619893
23.9952555783055 18.6598302958281 48.4204641715953
17.0523647853253 11.518037157788 43.0417655739052
57.5107395863171 40.4872578216636 24.938188234695
11.8320140526743 52.9077915021041 34.5723480775864
12.8754032313702 53.1795899126135 34.1309377040482
```

But I need my output to look exactly like this for the Fortran program to accept it.

```
***** SAMPLING PATTERN FILE

 50   3   1          0.0000
50
   87.54    62.84    17.00
   83.99    65.00    18.86
   84.44    63.68    18.63
   84.76    65.46    17.62
   13.46    16.99    49.68
   23.99    18.65    48.42
   17.05    11.51    43.04
   57.51    40.48    24.93
   11.83    52.90    34.57
   12.87    53.17    34.13
```

I should note, that I know exactly how to do the rounding in r by:

```
m=round(m$X,digits=2)
```

Is my best bet going to be simply using write.table and then formatting "by hand". Most of my models will then be created in a loop that I wrote in Fortran. I will only need to generate maybe a few dozen models in MixSim and then format them if that is the case. All models will have considerably more than 10 points.

Comment: You can get pretty close with `df <- signif(df, 4); write.table(df, 'df.txt', sep = '\t', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)`, but no headers, and it seems to drop trailing zeros for some reason. Surely somebody has written a Fortran-specific write function along the lines of `read.fortran`, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I think you can just apply `round` to the entire data.frame. `write.table` can have `sep="\t"` Saying it should "look like this" isn't that helpful. What are those items "50   3   1          0.0000\n
50", ... and does there need to be the first line that you have in code format? Be as specific as you possibly can.

Comment: @42, yes all of that needs to be there. 50 is the number of sample, 3 is number of groups, 1 should be the number of dimensions (in this example), and 0.000 is a placeholder for where a randomly generated number would have gone. `write.table` seems to truncate my decimal places and does not set each element 4 spaces away from each other as is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Tried a variety of things with write.table but always got undesired truncation of the decimal values when the trailing figures were `nn.00`.)

Use `cat` for the file preamble and `write.fwf` from pkg::gdata:

```
cat(top, file='out.txt')
install.packages('gdata')
gdata::write.fwf(signif(dat,4), file = "out.txt", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", 
                   colnames = FALSE)

-------result----------
***** SAMPLING PATTERN FILE

 50   3   1          0.0000
50
87.54   62.84   17.00
83.99   65.01   18.87
84.45   63.69   18.64
84.77   65.46   17.63
13.46   17.00   49.68
24.00   18.66   48.42
17.05   11.52   43.04
57.51   40.49   24.94
11.83   52.91   34.57
12.88   53.18   34.13
```

If you need padding on the LHS you can use `width=7` or 8.

Comment: Thanks, this still requires a small amount of editing after the fact, but I presume that is likely unavoidable because I am using a program written at a point in time in which Fortran required very strict indents and columns. So the formatting process will be a horror show, but less so now than before.

Comment: Indents should be possible with additional "blank" strings or blank columns possibly with column names of `"  "` at the appropriate points. Need a fully formed example to illustrate. In the exampole above I was able to get a blank column with a blank column name using `cbind(data.frame("       "="  ", check.names=FALSE), m$X)`